# Getting strings from a textfile in a combobox, vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Here is my code :
I'm trying to have some value out from a TXT file to a combobox or label but i feel combobox would be easier.

here's my code :

please note, some config.txt will only have 1 value while other 5-6

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim IDinFile As String
    Dim ID As String

    If IO.File.Exists("config.txt") Then

        Using StreamReader As New IO.StreamReader("config.txt")
            Do
                IDinFile = StreamReader.ReadLine
                If (IDinFile.IndexOf("7656")) <> -1 Then
                    ID = IDinFile.Substring(2)
                    ID = ID.Trim().Remove(ID.Length - 1)
                    ComboBox1.Items.Add(ID)
                    Exit Do
                End If
            Loop Until IDinFile Is Nothing
        End Using
    End If
End Sub
```

the file here in .png : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYaqP.png

Comment: That's json well invalid json, there is json parsers for this reason...

Comment: json or not, im able to get the first value in my combobox, but i cant get the nexts one. Also Im new to vbnet, well i read alot but i will search for json parsers tomorrow

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/ is a good online json parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-written the code for you. Problem was wrongly placed `Exit Do`. Also, its advisable to check the line before entering the loop rather than at the end of the loop.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim IDinFile As String
    Dim ID As String
    Const FILENAME As String = "config.txt"

    If IO.File.Exists(FILENAME) Then
        Using StreamReader As New IO.StreamReader(FILENAME)
            Do While StreamReader.Peek() >= 0
                IDinFile = StreamReader.ReadLine.Trim()
                If (IDinFile.IndexOf("7656")) <> -1 Then
                    ID = IDinFile.Substring(1, IDinFile.Length - 2)
                    ComboBox1.Items.Add(ID)
                End If
            Loop
        End Using
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot for helping me! I thought i really had to exit do!

Answer (score 1):

After you add the first item to the combobox you have an `Exit Do` statement. It no longer continues checking further lines and adding them to the combobox.

You should remove that statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It'll work if the values are organized line by line in the txt file.

```
    Dim srd as New StreamReader("config.txt")
    If io.file.exists("config.txt") then
    Dim str() = srd.ReadToEnd.split(environment.newline)
    For i = 0 to str.count-1
    Combobox.item.add(str(i))
    Next
    srd.close
```